# Android - create reusable method for AlertDialog

Tags: android

I try to create a class (classCommon) with re-usable methods that I plan to use for different projects.

Now the problem I have is that I want to create a re-usable method in that class for a YES\NO AlertDialog.

So basically I need to code
-an common\reusable AlertDialog that returns "true" (if YES was clicked) or "false"" if NO was clicked
-the main app has to wait til user actually has made a selection

I also have the feeling from my tests that the "main code" won't wait til the user has made a selection - somehow the AlertBox seems runs asyncroniosly (?) - so the main code will be executed regardless what the user selects in the AlertDialog?

So my question is:
I want to be able to write code like this:

```
main code:

//in my main code / Activity:
//call AlertDialog (MessageboxYESNO ) and *wait* til user made a selection, then contine
if ( classCommon._MessageboxYESNO ("Do you want to repeat the game ?","",myActivity.this) == true )
    { //do something if user select YES }
else
{   //do something if user select NO}
...
```

In classCommon I have created a method that shows the YES\NO AlertDialog - but I don't' know how to return true/false to the calling (main) code.

classCommon:  (what I have so far)

```
public static void (boolean?) _MessageboxYESNO(String sTitle, String sMessage, final Context myContext)
    {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);

        builder
                .setTitle(sTitle)
                .setMessage(sMessage)
                .setCancelable(false)                                
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public  void  (boolean?) onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Yes button clicked, do something

                        //return true ?
                    }
                })

                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //no button clicked, do something

                        //return false ?
                     }
                })
                .show();

        //return  true/false ?

    }
```

Comment: I did same thing for some time ago. You need to create an interface. By which from every class when you call that alert it will call back to your class.

Comment: We cannot create a method to be used for different projects, unless you create your own android-library. We only can create a method to be used for the same project.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is not possible, because it depends on Events.

But I will give you an alternative: Create an Interface with 2 methods: OnYesClicked() and OnNoClicked(). Then you should implement this interface into the class which you invoke the MessageBox method, and pass "this" as a parameter.

The custom Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface{

   public void onYesClicked();

   public void onNoClicked();
}
```

with this, you can do something when you click Yes or No.

```
public static void _MessageboxYESNO(String sTitle, String sMessage, final Context myContext, MyInterface myInterface)
{
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);

    builder
            .setTitle(sTitle)
            .setMessage(sMessage)
            .setCancelable(false)                                
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public  void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Yes button clicked, do something

                    myInterface.onYesClicked();
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //no button clicked, do something

                     myInterface.onNoClicked();
                 }
            })
            .show();
}
```

and this would be your call:

```
public class AClass implements MyInterface{

    @Override
    public void onYesClicked(){
       //Do Something
   }

   @Override
    public void onNoClicked(){
        //Do other thing
    }

    public void openDialog()
    {
     classCommon._MessageboxYESNO ("Do you want to repeat the game ?","",myActivity.this,this);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try it.  I'*m new to java and also to the usage of interfaces...so I have a question:  Is myInterface.onYesClicked(); correct or shoudl it be AClass.onYesClicked();  ?

Comment: Is the interface correct, because it allows you reusability in any Class. You just need to implement the interface in your desired classes (implementing an interface is somewhat similar to extending a class).

Comment: I just was surprised that  myInterface.onYesClicked(); will work because there is no code in  myInterface.onYesClicked();  
I know that inferfaces have no code, just method signatures...so I wonder how the code in  myInterface.onYesClicked();  will be run.  
And second what I dont understand: the class "AClass" - this has the actual code - but this call is never used.. ?